# Custom "contains" method for list

Tags: python, doubly-linked-list

I'd like to get a better handle on the doubly-linked structure. The goal in this scenario is to append a range of values to the end of a list. I then would like to test for a value I know should be in the list, this should return true, and vice versa for a value that I know shouldn't be in the list. So here's what I have thus far.

```
class LinkedList:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, val, prior=None, next=None):
            self.val = val
            self.prior = prior
            self.next  = next

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = LinkedList.Node(None) # sentinel node (never to be removed)
        self.head.prior = self.head.next = self.head # set up "circular" topology
        self.length = 0

    def append(self, value):
        n = LinkedList.Node(value, prior=self.head.prior, next=self.head)
        n.prior.next = n.next.prior = n
        self.length += 1

    def _normalize_idx(self, idx):
        nidx = idx
        if nidx < 0:
            nidx += len(self)
            if nidx < -1:
                raise IndexError  
        return nidx

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        """Implements `x = self[idx]`"""
        nidx = self._normalize_idx(idx)
        currNode = self.head.next
        for i in range(nidx):
            currNode = currNode.next
        if nidx >= len(self):
            raise IndexError
        return currNode.val


    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        """Implements `self[idx] = x`"""
        nidx = self._normalize_idx(idx)
        currNode = self.head.next
        if nidx >= len(self):
            raise IndexError
        for i in range(nidx):
            currNode = currNode.next
        currNode.val = value

    def __iter__(self):
        """Supports iteration (via `iter(self)`)"""
        cursor = self.head.next
        while cursor is not self.head:
            yield cursor.val
            cursor = cursor.next

    def __len__(self):
        """Implements `len(self)`"""
        return self.length

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return len(self) == len(other) and all(
            val1 == val2 for val1, val2 in zip(self, other))

    def __contains__(self, value):
        """Implements `val in self`. Returns true if value is found in this list."""
        return all(val1 == value for val1 in zip(self))
```

Test:

```
    lst = LinkedList()
    for i in range(100):
        lst.append(i)
    tc.assertFalse(100 in lst)
    tc.assertTrue(50 in lst)
```

When I test this code I get I get an Assertion error saying " False is not true " I'm unsure why my code is able to recognize that the value 100 isn't in the list, whereas it also says 50 isn't and returns False when it should return True.

Comment: Use any instead of all. Also, you don't need the zip.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is wrong. Your `__contains__` function only returns true if **all** values in your linked list are equal to a given test value. I.e. it'd only be true if all values in your linked list are equal to one another *as well*:

```
>>> value = 'foo'
>>> all(val1 == value for val1 in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
False
>>> all(val1 == value for val1 in ['foo', 'foo', 'foo'])
True
```

Moreover, the `zip()` call in that generator expression is entirely redundant, you are not pairing up elements from multiple iterables here.

Use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) instead:

```
return any(v == value for v in self)
```

`all()` will only return `True` if *all* items in the iterable are true (it'll return `False` early). `any()` will return `True` as soon as it finds *any one* item in the iterable that is true:

```
>>> any(val1 == value for val1 in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
True
>>> any(val1 == value for val1 in ['foo', 'foo', 'foo'])
True
>>> any(val1 == value for val1 in ['spam', 'bar', 'baz'])
False
```